# What is this equipment Lara and Jonah are wearing in Shadow of the Tomb Raider?

Tags: shadow-of-the-tomb-raider

[image: Screenshot from Shadow of the tomb raider]

I'm playing a new game plus mode (from downloaded save game) in Shadow of the Tomb Raider. I have noticed that both Lara and Jonah are wearing some weird looking equipment. I can't find any inventory option in which I can hide it.

What is it and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a flashlight that is attachable to pieces of clothing. Sorry to say, but you can't get rid of it.

You can see it an action on this Youtube. 
<sub>(The purpose of the video was to  show a lighting issue with it, but I'm using it as a visual of what it is)</sub>

Comment: Are you absolutely sure we can't hide it or something? no matter what i outfit i wear it's there. It's looking really annoying.

Comment: @KalyanamKiran As far as I am aware, you can't hide it. I played the snot out of the game and there was never an option to remove it

Comment: well i only noticed it now, i could've sworn it wasn't there when i was playing regular mode yesterday. Oh well :(

Comment: Looks it'll appear when exploring dark areas and will go away on it's own a little while after exploring.